# Get a webpage 'object' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

There is a webpage online that has a vast field of data I need to record.
And like every normal person I don't want to do it by hand.
So, is it possible to 'import' a webpage 'object' that would give me access to the data fields". So like:

```
    myWebpage.getElementById("field1").value;
```

would return the data in the 'imported' field.
Any help on this would be appreciated. Or any other alternatives.
Thanks

Or if somebody has any easier way that this can be done in any other language feel free to share!

Comment: Every page is different.  So every solution will be different.  Therefore, asking how to do this generally is a silly question.

Comment: Not when you are logging the same page over and over. Yes I am writing very narrow minded code if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/)

Here is an example, getting some elements from a webpage:

```
var page = new WebPage(),
    url = 'http://lite.yelp.com/search?find_desc=pizza&find_loc=94040&find_submit=Search';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var results = page.evaluate(function() {
            var list = document.querySelectorAll('span.address'), pizza = [], i;
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                pizza.push(list[i].innerText);
            }
            return pizza;
        });
        console.log(results.join('\n'));
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your skill set.  If you can learn a scripting language like Ruby or Python, it is very easy to write web crawlers/scrapers in these languages.  Google web crawler in (insert language) and you will easily find them.

If you are not so programatically inclined, you can try a FF extension such as this one:

http://www.outwit.com/

Also take a look at this info:

http://www.slideshare.net/michelleminkoff/almost-scraping-web-scraping-without-programming